# `rake doc:app` not working in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

Why is this not working? This command is supposed to generate documentation.

```
$ rake doc:app
Don't know how to build task 'doc:app' (see --tasks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake doc` tasks have been deprecated in Rails 5. [Source.](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd7cc5254b090ccbb84dcee4408a5acede25ef2a)